# storing and retrieving ajax xml response in sessionStorage

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I am getting XML response from ajax and then I am trying to store it in sessionStorage but I cannot retrieve it.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/webservice.svc/getProfile',
        data: { "memberId": $(authenticateResponse).find("memberId").text() },
        method: "GET",
        async: false,
        success: function (d) {
            sessionStorage.clear();
            sessionStorage.setItem('ALMS', d);
        }
    });
```

When I try to retrieve

```
console.dirxml(sessionStorage.ALMS)
[object XMLDocument]
console.dirxml($(sessionStorage.ALMS))
```

What I am doing wrong !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: @ChetanJoshi similar, but not the same. That's about objects, this is about XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that `sessionStorage` can only hold strings. Due to this the XMLDocument is being coerced using `toString()`, hence the value you're seeing.

To fix this you need to serialise the XMLDocument manually before saving it. Try this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/webservice.svc/getProfile',
  data: { 
    memberId: $(authenticateResponse).find("memberId").text() 
  },
  method: "GET",
  success: function (d) {
    sessionStorage.clear();
    sessionStorage.setItem('ALMS', new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(d));
  }
});
```

Also note that I removed `async: false` as it's incredibly bad practice.